# Difference between these two types of declaration in c++

Tags: c++

for this structure

```
struct node{
int no;
node *next;
};
```

what is the difference between these two types of declarations?

```
node *New=new node;
```

and

```
node *New;
```

Comment: One initializes the variable right at the point of declaration. The other leaves it uninitialized, containing random garbage (you can assign a valid value to it later, of course).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik who said that it is a local variable?

Comment: It doesn't only initialize the pointer. It creates a new instance of a node structure and assigns the address to the New pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always initialize a variable when declaring it so that you know it is a good know state.  when working with pointer either grab "new" memory at the time of the pointers creation or use nullptr.

```
node * New = new node; // Okay. We know New holds a good node and we can call delete on it
node * New = nullptr; // Okay. We know we can delete on it without crashing
node * New; // Bad.  We dont know what the state of New is and we can't call delete on it
```

Answer (score 2):

```
node *New=new node;
```

This is initializing the pointer which is good thing to remember.

Whereas

```
node *New;
```

not which is a bad thing as chances of de-referencing it in it's naked form are there.

Comment: To the memory you just allocated with `new`.... you seriously need to read an introductory C++ text

Comment: `node *New=0x0;` would also initialize the pointer. The important bit is that it allocates memory, for a `node` object, and calls the ctor.

Answer (score 2):

```
node *New=new node;
```

Creates a variable called `New` and initializes it with pointer, returned by `operator new`

```
node *New;
```

Depends on context, for namespace (global) context creates a variable, initialized by `nullptr`, or for local creates one uninitialized.

Answer (score -2):

Both nod *New = new node; and node *New; are invalid declaration types. The reason why it allows the lines at all is because the programmer has declared a keyword as a declared structure. They are both bad lines of code. What you have so far is a pointer to a new structure(but not really). New is a keyword that instantiates an object that is greater in precedence than the current scope of the code block. Whenever an object is made eventually it must be unmade with the delete keyword.

Comment: `New is a keyword that instantiates an object`... This is incorrect. There is no keyword `New`. You're confusing it with `new` which is a keyword. Both lines are valid declarations.

Comment: New was the start of the sentence.

Comment: Ok, then what makes the declarations invalid? Why are the lines of code *bad*? Why doesn't OP *really* have a pointer to a new structure (well, a new *instance* actually, which they obviously don't have in the second declaration but they do have a pointer to a valid instance in the first declaration, don't they)? What does `programmer has declared a keyword as a declared structure` mean?

Comment: I would make an object with a public constructor, not a public structure(user defined object). Then we can forget the #include <new>;